# Konjuntiv II vom Verb sterben: »ich stärbe« vs. »ich stürbe«

Tags: subjunctive, preterite, irregular-verb

Ich habe mehrmals gelesen und mir immer gedacht, dass sich die Formen des Konjunktiv II an den Formen des Präteritum orientieren *müssten*.

Bei regelmäßigen Verben ist kein Unterschied zu merken. Zum Beispiel: beim Verb *kaufen* haben wir die Form *ich kaufte* sowohl im Präteritum als auch im Konjuntiv II (was übrigens auch ein Grund dafür wäre, dass man beim Konjunktiv II eher die zusammengesetzte Form *ich würde kaufen* bevorzugt).

Bei unregelmäßigen Verben dagegen findet man einen Unterschied zwischen den Formen. Zumindest an der Endung (z. B.: beim Verb *schreiben*: *ich schrieb* vs. *ich schrieb**e***), aber sehr oft auch am Umlaut, wenn der Vokal überhaupt einen Umlaut bekommen kann: *ich gab* vs. *ich gäbe*; *ich war* vs. *ich wäre*; *ich bot* vs. *ich böte*; *ich fuhr* vs. *ich führe*, usw.

Also: soweit ich es verstanden hatte, hätte die Form des Konjuntivs II immer etwas zu tun mit der des Präteritums. Bis gestern hatte ich das so verstanden.

Aber gestern bin ich auf die Form **ich stürbe** gestoßen. Hätte man mich nach der Form des Konjuntivs II des Verbs *sterben* gefragt, dann hätte ich ihm ganz sicher und bedenkenlos geantwortet: das Präteritum von der Form *ich sterbe* ist *ich starb*; dann muss die Form des Konjuntivs II *ich stärbe* heißen.

Es scheint aber dass es nicht ganz so einfach ist, auch wenn ich mir ziemlich sicher bin, auf die Form *ich stärbe* schon irgendwann auch gestoßen zu sein.

Gibt es etwa beide Formen? Und wenn ja, gibt es irgendeinen Unterschied zwischen ihnen?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Ursprünglicher Präteritumstamm mit *u*

Die Formen *stürbe/hülfe* widersprechen nur scheinbar der Regel, dass der Konjunktiv präteritum sich aus der umgelauteten Präteritumform bildet. Die älteren Sprachstufen unterschieden nämlich zwei verschiedene Präteritumsstämme. In der dritten Ablautreihe, zu der Wörter wie *finden, singen, helfen, sterben, werden* usw. gehören, gab es einerseits einen Präteritumstamm mit *a* (z.B. *ich fand/sang/half/starb)* und einen Präteritumstamm mit *u* (z.B. *wir funden/sungen/hulfen/sturben).*

Im modernen Neuhochdeutsch hat ein Ausgleich stattgefunden, normalerweise zugunsten des Präteritumstamms mit *a* (vgl. *wir fanden/sangen/halfen/starben*), gelegentlich abar auch zugunsten des Präteritumstamms mit *u* (vgl. *ich wurde* – neben der archaischen Reliktform *(ich) ward,* in der sich ein Rest der alten Zweiformigkeit erhalten hat).

Der Konjunktiv präteritum ist ursprünglich immer aus dem Präteritumstamm mit *u* gebildet worden. Die Formen *stürbe/hülfe* usw. sind also ganz regelmässig umgelautet aus *(wir) sturben/hulfen* – genau so wie *würde* aus *(wir) wurden.*

## Homophonievermeidung

Die Formen *stürbe* und *hülfe* sind im Unterschied zu anderen Formen wie *‌*sünge/bünde* bis heute erhalten geblieben. Dies liegt wohl daran, dass die umgelauteten Formen des Präteritumstamms mit *a* genau gleich ausgesprochen wird wie die Formen im Präsens indikativ. Die Formen *(wir) stärben/hälfen* und *(wir) sterben/helfen* unterscheiden sich in der Aussprache nicht, wohl aber die Formen *(wir) stürben/hülfen.* Im Indikativ kennt die moderne Sprache nur den Präteritumstamm mit *a* (vgl. *wir starben/halfen),* doch im Konjunktiv hat sich zur Homophonievermeidung der Präteritumstamms mit *u* als Umlaut erhalten (vgl. *stürbe/hülfe).*

Anders verhält es sich bei den Formen *(wir) bänden/sängen,* die regelhaft aus dem modernen Präteritumstamm mit *a* gebildet sind. Sie unterscheiden sich in der Aussprache von den Formen *(wir) binden/singen.* Daher gab es keinen Grund zur Beibehaltung von Formen wie *‌*sünge/bünde.*

Ohne entsprechende Indikativ-Formen mit *u* stehen die Formen *hülfe/stürbe* allerdings auf wackeligen Füssen. Es fehlt ihnen gewissermassen der Rückhalt in einem nicht umgelauteten Pendant des Präteritumstamms mit *u.* Daher ist es verständlich, dass sie in Konkurrenz stehen zu den Formen *hälfe/stärbe,* die sich regelhaft aus dem modernen Präteritumstamm mit *a* bilden – so wie die Formen *sänge/bände* usw.

## Geschriebene Sprache

Bei den regelhaften Formen *hälfe/stärbe* spielt die Homophonie mit dem Indikativ präsens *(helfe/sterbe)* offensichtlich keine Rolle. Dies dürfte ein Hinweis darauf sein, dass die Entwicklung dieser Formen nicht mehr in der gesprochenen Sprache stattfindet, sondern in der geschriebenen. In der gesprochenen Sprache klingen *(ich) hülfe/stürbe* altertümlich und absurd, *(ich) hälfe/stärbe* hingegen missverständlich – man sagt vielmehr *(ich) würde helfen/würde sterben.* In der geschriebnen Sprache hingegen macht sich das Altertümliche weniger bemerkbar, und die Missverständlichkeit besteht überhaupt nicht.

Comment: Großartige Antwort!

Comment: Auf den Unterschied Singular/Plural bis ins frühe Neuhochdeutsche wollte ich auch schon hinweisen, aber es ist viel besser, wenn das jemand tut, der tatsächlich weiß, wovon er schreibt ;)

Answer (score 6):

Es sind zumindest theoretisch beide Formen denkbar, aber »stürbe« ist weitaus häufiger als »stärbe«, wie dieses [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=st%C3%A4rbe%2Cst%C3%BCrbe&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cst%C3%A4rbe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cst%C3%BCrbe%3B%2Cc0) zeigt:

[image]

Man sieht, dass beide Konjunktiv-Varianten mit der Zeit immer seltener verwendet werden, man sieht aber auch, dass »stärbe« verglichen mit »stürbe« so gut wie nicht vorhanden ist. Wenn man nämlich »stürbe« aus dem Ngram entfernt, kommt das heraus (Vergleiche die Skalierung der Y-Achse, im oberen Bild ist der höchste Wert 0,000550 mit 3 Nullen vor der ersten signifikanten Ziffer, im zweiten Bild 0,0000220 mit 4 Nullen, das zweite Bild ist also entlang der Y-Achse um das 25-fache vergrößert):

[image]

Wenn man sich auf die Zeit nach 1950 beschränkt, erhält man ein Ngram, das ein klareres Bild der gegenwärtigen Verhältnisse zeigt:

[image]

Nur »stärbe« ohne »stürbe«:

[image]

In der halbwegs gegenwärtigen Zeit hat »stärbe« im Jahr 1995 eine maximale Häufigkeit von 0,00000011%. Das heißt: Unter 909 Millionen Wörtern, die 1995 in Büchern gedruckt wurden, ist genau eines »stärbe«.

»Stürbe« trat 1995 mit einer Häufigkeit von 0,000014% auf, es war also eines von 7,14 Millionen Wörtern, und damit 127-mal häufiger als »stärbe«. In jedem anderen Jahr der letzen 60 Jahre ist das Verhältnis noch extremer.

Bei diesem Verhältnis kann man durchaus davon ausgehen, dass die wenigen Fälle, in denen »stärbe« verwendet wurde, auf einen Fehler zurückzuführen sind. Man kann also sagen, dass nur »stürbe« die richtige Form ist, und dass »stärbe« falsch ist.

Answer (score 5):

Konjunktiv II ist eine selten verwendete Form, bei der sich deswegen viele schwer tun.

Im Falle von "sterben" sind sich auch viele Wörterbücher nicht sicher, man findet sowohl "stürbe" als auch (seltener) "stärbe".

Wobei genaugenommen *hälfe* (statt *hülfe*), *stärbe* (statt *stürbe*), *stände* (statt *stünde*) usw. von Deutsch-Puristen als falsch betrachtet wird (Diese drei Beispiele widerlegen übrigens auch alle schön deine "Präteritum"-These). Duden sagt "stürbe", dict.cc "stärbe", Die-Konjugation.de nennt zur Sicherheit beide Formen, Wikipedia meint "stürbe" und irgendwo habe ich eine Tabelle gefunden, die sich in ihrer Not mit "würde sterben" behalf.

Bei "helfen" und "stehen" befindet sich die Mauer der Puristen zugegebenermaßen schon in Auflösung - Dort hat die "a"-Form schon größtenteils den Weg in die Wörterbücher als erlaubte Alternative gefunden. Möglicherweise macht "sterben" gerade dieselbe Entwicklung durch.

Ich persönlich glaube, die richtige Form war schon immer (noch, das mag sich möglicherweise in Bewegung befinden) *stürbe*.

Wie immer, wenn sich Wörterbücher nicht einigen können, hilft *ngrams*, hier mit einer (ziemlich) eindeutigen Antwort (man beachte den gelben Kasten):

[image]

Comment: It's also interesting to note that the usage of **sterben würde** appears to cross **stürbe** at about 1995, and then almost doubles in 2010. I've also read that many more prefer the *würde* form nowadays, as forms like *hülfe* and *stürbe* become old-fashioned. By the way, you can check the "case-insensitive" box so that you don't need to type both the capital and lowercase forms.

Comment: @SkeletonBow I wouldn't necessarily say the "Hilfskonjunktiv" using *würde* is replacing something "old-fashioned". It's just much simpler to use and doesn't involve any learning. And nowadays it's *allowed*. When I was in school, this was still considered "wrong" and earned you  bad credits... - And what you see in the ngrams is the result of ticking "case-intensitive"  ;)

Comment: Really? That's interesting! It didn't say that in the book I learned about it from :) but it's good to know the different perspectives, so thank you for that! I usually can... impress people when I use *stürbe*, anyway, so I guess I'll use that (formally, anyway). And I see, it said "stürbe (All)" for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Ja, es gibt beide Formen. Beim *Konjunktiv Präteritum* gibt es immer wieder konkurrierende Formen, vor allem mit ö/ä (begönne/begänne, rönne/ränne, schwömme/schwämme), aber eben auch ü/ä (stünde/stände).