# Konjunktiv II von „gebären“

Tags: subjunctive, inflection

Ich war unlängst sehr überrascht irgendwo *(sie) gebärt* statt *gebiert* zu lesen (ja *gebiert* ist die Form, die mir natürlich erscheint, auch wenn der geschätzte Editor dies wohl ausschloß, was ich mittlerweile verstehe).  Dadurch kam es zu einer Diskussion, welche zeigte, dass auch ich mir beim Konjunktiv II etwas unsicher bin. Ich bemühte Google und stieß auf [diese Seite über Konjugation des deutschen Verbs *gebären*](https://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/?w=geb%C3%A4ren%20). Diese Seite flößt mir schon dadurch wenig Vertrauen ein, daß sie bei *[verwenden](https://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/?w=verwenden)* das Partizip *verwandt* und das assoziierte Präteritum unterschlägt. Dies sind nun wirklich Formen die man kennen muss (und die auch der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verwandt_verwenden_benutzen) noch nicht vergessen hat)!

Nach einiger Überlegung bin ich sehr gegen den dort vertretenen Konjunktiv II *ich gebäre*. Der Grund ist der, dass bei deutschen Verben mit zwei in Frage kommenden Vokalen (welche natürlich nicht willkürlich sind!) meiner Vermutung nach so gewählt wird, dass sich der Konjunktiv II vom Indikativ Präsens unterscheidet (eine Verwechslungsgefahr mit dem Präteritum ist m.E. kaum je gegeben, daher kann man dort Gleichheit zulassen, vgl. *sagen*). Dies gilt umso mehr als der Konjunktiv II den Konjunktiv I ersetzt, wenn dieser vom Präsens akustisch nicht zu unterscheiden ist. Darum sagt man auch *hülfe, würfe, stürbe und *schölte* (bei letzterem verzeichnet [Verbformen.de](https://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/schelten.htm) an erster Stelle *schälte*). Ich plädiere demnach für *ich geböre,* allerdings nicht ohne einen Rest Unsicherheit.

Das Buch [Der Teutschen Sprache Stammbaum und Fortwachs oder Teutscher Sprachschatz](https://books.google.at/books?id=6KZNAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT525&lpg=PT525&dq=geb%C3%B6re&source=bl&ots=WZsnufxvmz&sig=MrpJEYALmvx5HJzkYfo08_zxI40&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjciPfVupnYAhUGD8AKHUOoB14Q6AEILjAE#v=onepage&q=geb%C3%B6re&f=false) schlägt offenbar gleichfalls *ich geböre* vor, jedoch nur neben *ich gebiere!*

Was sagen eure Nachschlagwerke, Quellen, oder das gute alte Bauchgefühl?

---

Edit:

Daß die Formen wie *stürbe* nicht willkürlich gebildet werden dürfen, ist mir spätestens seit dieser [Antwort auf StE](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/32704/16039) sehr bewußt. Ich hätte in diesem Fall das Indiz auf Berechtigung im Partizipialstamm gesehen, analog zu *begonnen* –> *begönne*. Eigentlich sollte ich nach älteren Präterita suchen, nur weiß ich nicht, wie man das anstellt.

Edit:

Obwohl Herr Schölnast mich überzeugt hat, daß diese Form nicht mehr in Gebrauch ist, werde ich Texte, in denen sie auftritt, hier aufführen. Es ist überaus bedauerlich, daß sich eine etwaige frühere Vorherrschaft der heute gebräuchlichen Form ob des Zusammenfallens mit dem Indikativ nicht so leicht ergooglen läßt. Ich verspreche dennoch, auch solche alten Beispiele, so ich sie denn finde, getreulich aufzuführen!

[Quelle aus dem Jahre 1544](https://books.google.at/books?id=WKkaV4I8DVMC&pg=PP109&lpg=PP109&dq=geb%C3%B6re%20sie&source=bl&ots=QOEilgsC8w&sig=vfsHI8VSPytiLTBvNEtjpu4b-hA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3s_6klZvYAhVnAcAKHRuuCWgQ6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=geb%C3%B6re&f=false)

[Quelle aus dem Jahre 1788](https://books.google.at/books?id=g9cGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA493&lpg=PA493&dq=geb%C3%B6re%20eine&source=bl&ots=DDo56svPej&sig=gmooy2Z8uuDb789MzI5WccvhWL4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj73vqJp5vYAhWEBcAKHV6XCh4Q6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=geb%C3%B6re%20eine&f=false)

[Quelle aus dem Jahre 1790](https://books.google.at/books?id=9e1bAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=geb%C3%B6re%20sie&source=bl&ots=N1XC1SwVrl&sig=3lpJdJInnfHY2t-HYYpms7wQxko&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3s_6klZvYAhVnAcAKHRuuCWgQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=geb%C3%B6re%20sie&f=false)

[Gottfried Kellers Gasele No XII aus dem Jahre 1847](https://www.gottfriedkeller.ch/GG/EG/NG_04.htm)

Comment: Die genannten Beispiele leiten sich alle vom Vokal `e` ab, hier noch eines mit ähnlicher Umlautsituation: *schwöre* (Präsens) / *schwor* (Präteritum) / *schwüre* (Konjunktiv II). Wie man sieht, hat sich auch hier der Umlaut geändert, um sich vom Präsens zu unterscheiden.

Comment: Ja, die Form ist auch nicht abwegig, sondern folgt einem möglichen Bildungsmuster aus dem Partizip (siehe meine Antwort), das sich aber eben nicht durchgesetzt hat. Der Versuch zur graphisch-phonetischen Distinktion ist auch im Eintrag "gebären" im DWB (Grimm) unter I.c)α) dokumentiert: "die starke bildung, mhd. gebir, gebar, gebâren, geborn, hat sich nhd. besonders gut erhalten; doch geht man dem conj. praet. gebäre (mhd. gebære) aus dem wege, weil er mit dem praes. nhd. zusammenfällt (mhd. vielmehr ich gebir, wir gebërn), aber aus dem 16. jahrh. gepär s. II, 4, b."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das Buch, das dich (wenn auch nur halbherzig) in deinem Plädoyer unterstützt, ist im 17. Jahrhundert erschienen (*»Im Jahr des Herren 1691.«*). So ein alter Schinken erwärmt zwar jedem Sammler antiquarischer Bücher das Herz, ist aber als Referenzwerk für die deutsche Sprache des 21. Jahrhunderts völlig wertlos.

**Was sagen moderne Nachschlagwerke?**

1. Die Seite [Verbformen.de](https://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/?w=geb%C3%A4ren), die du ja selbst bereits gefunden hast, ist ein hervorragendes Nachschlagewerk für solche Fragen wie du sie gestellt hast:

   > ich gebäre, du gebärest, er/sie/es gebäre
2. Ebenfalls sehr gut ist [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/geb%C3%A4ren), dort findest du auch zu jedem Verb eine vollständige [Flexionstabelle](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:geb%C3%A4ren):

   > ich gebäre, du gebärest (gebärst), er/sie/es gebäre
3. Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gebaeren) gibt (zumindest in diesem Fall, sonst nicht immer) ebenfalls die gewünschte Auskunft:

   > ich gebäre, du gebärest (gebärst), er/sie/es gebäre
4. Dann gibt es noch den [Konjugator von Reverso](http://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-geb%C3%A4ren.html), der ebenfalls eine vollständige Flexionstabelle anzeigt:

   > ich gebäre, du gebärest, er/sie/es gebäre
5. Ebenso [Cactus2000](https://conjd.cactus2000.de/showverb.php?verb=gebaeren):

   > ich gebäre, du gebärest, er/sie/es gebäre

Ich glaube, du erkennst das Muster.

---

**Was sagt mein Bauchgefühl?**

Es schließt sich der Mehrheit der Muttersprachler an, deren Meinung ja in den Nachschlagewerken wiedergegeben wird:

Den Konjunktiv II verwendet man beispielsweise für irreale Konditionalsätze, also um etwas auszudrücken, das von einer unerfüllbaren Bedingung abhängt:

> Wäre ich eine hochschwangere Frau, so **gebäre** ich in den nächsten Tagen ein Kind.
>   Wärest du eine hochschwangere Frau, so **gebärest** du in den nächsten Tagen ein Kind.
>   Wäre Hans eine hochschwangere Frau, so **gebäre** er in den nächsten Tagen ein Kind.
>   Wären wir beide zwei hochschwangere Frauen, so **gebären** wir in den nächsten Tagen zwei Kinder.
>   Wäret ihr beide zwei hochschwangere Frauen, so **gebäret** ihr in den nächsten Tagen zwei Kinder.
>   Wären Hans und Kurt zwei hochschwangere Frauen, so **gebären** sie in den nächsten Tagen zwei Kinder.

Comment: Sehr überzeugend recherchiert. Offenbar hinkt mein Sprachgefühl der Norm (weiter noch als sonst) hinterher!

Answer (score 7):

Der Gedanke geht etwas zu weit. Grundsätzlich ist es so, dass der Konjunktiv II anhand des Präteritalstamms gebildet wird, wobei bei starken Verben nach Möglichkeit der Umlaut des Präteritalstamms gesetzt wird. Zum Beispiel:

- geben - Präteritalstamm: g**a**b - Konjunktiv II: g**ä**be
- helfen - h**a**lf - h**ä**lfe
- gebären - geb**a**r - geb**ä**re

Eine Reihe starker Verben weichen von diesem Bildungsmuster allerdings ab oder verfügen über Nebenformen mit abweichendem Vokal:

- helfen - h**a**lf - h**ü**lfe
- sterben - st**a**rb - st**ü**rbe

Der Ursprung dieser Nebenformen ist jedoch unterschiedlich. Teilweise verwenden sie den Vokal aus dem Partizipialstamm:

- beginnen - begann - Konjunktiv II: beg**ö**nne (wegen Partizipialstamm: beg**o**nn-)

Teilweise wird ein alter Ablautvokal der Pluralform im Präteritum verwendet:

- werfen - warf - Konjunktiv II: w**ü**rfe (wegen des mittelhochdeutschen Präteritums: sie w**u**rfen)

(Zu alledem: Zifonun et al., Grammatik der deutschen Sprache, Bd. 3, 1997, S. 1733 f.)

Aber: Das ist alles uneinheitlich und hat oft sehr unterschiedliche sprachhistorische Gründe. Man darf *nicht* beliebige Umlaute wählen, um den Konjunktiv II vom Präsens zu unterscheiden. Und wie ein anderer Antwortender hier schon illustrativ gezeigt hat: Eine Form "geböre" wird standardsprachlich nicht verwendet.

Comment: Sehr interessant! Bei “hälfe” streuben sich mir die Nackenhaare und gehört habe ich es auch noch nie, aber theoretisch kann ich Ihnen folgen.

Comment: Wäre es denn ein beliebiger Umlaut? Wäre es nicht genau, wie bei “begönne” der Partizipialstamm?

Comment: Ja, wäre es. Ich wollte einfach nur darauf hinweisen, dass diese Bildungen nicht einer Einheitslogik folgen, wie in der Frage angedeutet, sondern grds. verschiedene Formen mit unterschiedlichen Argumenten rationalisierbar sind, wobei sich letztlich mal die eine, mal die andere durchgesetzt hat. Deswegen geht der Gedanke, man könnte da jetzt eine "richtige" Form finden, zu weit, und mit dem "beliebigen" Umlaut wollte ich nur sagen, dass man nicht leichterhand ein bestimmtes Rationalisierungsargument als das "richtige" herauspicken darf. Nicht mehr, nicht weniger :).

Comment: @ johnl das sehe ich ein :)